# Ubuntu guest VM with host-only adapter - how to APT?

Tags: apt, vmware, vmware-workstation

I work for a company with strict security requirements. IT cleared me to install a Ubuntu VM on my workstation with VMWare, on the condition that it be kept off our domain network by giving it a host-only network adapter.

That's all fine and dandy, but I'm left wondering how I can install software I would need? For now, assume that this machine is absolutely not allowed to connect to the LAN and likely cannot have internet access, and may only "speak" to the host OS... what are my options for installing software I'd normally get from APT repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a mirror of the packages you need on your local machine, and then point /etc/apt/sources.list at that mirror. https://apt-mirror.github.io/ is one such tool for doing that.

Comment: Sadly, my host is a Windows one so this won't work for me, but for anyone running a Debian-based host this looks useful!